# regex python non alpha num characters

Tags: python, regex

I have string which is as below (aim is to get rid of non alphanum chars BETWEEN alpha num chars except at end of string)

string: `This$#is% Matrix#  %!`

what i want: `This is Matrix#  %!`

so I want to get rid of non alpha num only between, not at the end.

I tried this regex code, `str1 = re.sub(r'([^\s\w]|_)+', ' ', str1)` but it gets rid of all non-alp including one at the end.

How do i solve this tricky problem

Comment: find the index of the last alphanumeric character, `i` and apply regex from index `0` to `i`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative lookahead assertion.

```
>>> s = "This$#is% Matrix#  %!"
>>> re.sub(r'([^\s\w]|_)+(?![^\w]*$)', ' ', s)
'This is  Matrix#  %!'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you make two passes:

1. Replace a bunch of "bad" characters with a space.
2. Replace a bunch of spaces with a single space.

You have said you want to only remove bad character when there are alphanumerics following. You can use a zero-width lookahead for that:

```
bad_chars = r'([^\s\w]|_)+(?=\s*\w)'
```

The `(?=...)` is a [positive lookahead,](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and it *looks ahead* to see if the pattern `\s*\w` is matched from the current position, but *does not* move forward- it just looks.

Then replace with spaces, collapse the spaces, and you're done:

```
re.sub(bad_chars, ' ', mystring)
re.sub('\s\s+', ' ', mystring)
print(mystring)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I feel my question still hasnt been answered,as you can see in the output below, I only want the non alpha num between the 2 alpha chars to be replace by 1 space, the part after matrix, should be untouched as its not between alphanum chars.

Inout string This$#is% Matrix#(2 space here)  %!

Your Output (stdout)
This is Matrix#(1 space here) %!

Expected OutputDownload
This is Matrix#(2 space here)%!